# UILabel text wrapping in a UITableView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I am having trouble getting a UILabel to wrap properly in a `UITableView's` `tableHeaderView`.  My goal is to have a `UILabel` which expands the height of a `UITableView's` header view dynamically, based on the amount of text that I have in the label.

I am attempting to follow the same approach which works when the `UILabel` is within a simple `UIView` wrapper.  My approach is derived from this [guide and associated project](http://devetc.org/code/2014/07/07/auto-layout-and-views-that-wrap.html).  I am successful in repeating the example - my toggle button results in the height of the superview expanding on click.  Unfortunately I have not been successful in implementing this within a `UITableView's` view header.

**Exhibit 1: Single UIView Wrapper (works)**

Shown below (`UIView` superview in green, `UILabel` in grey):
[image: Exhibit 1 Constraints]

Per the instructions from the guide, I subclass the `UILabel's` encapsulating view with an implementation of `layoutSubviews` which adjusts the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, like so:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat availableLabelWidth = self.label.frame.size.width;
    self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = availableLabelWidth;

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

**Exhibit 2: Outer UIView wrapper (works)**

As a next step, I've successfully encapsulated the `UILabel` within another `UIView`, to verify that I can get the outer `UIView` to expand as well.  Shown below (outer `UIView` in green, inner `UIView` in white, `UILabel` in grey):

[image: Exhibit 2 Inner Constraints]

Outer UIView constraints:
[image: Exhibit 2 Outer Constraints]

I used the same `layoutSubviews` approach as listed above.  In this example, both encapsulating `UIViews`' heights are adjusted to fit the `UILabel`.

**Exhibit 3: Table View Header (doesn't work)**

Now for rolling this `UILabel` example into the table view header. I follow the same approach as Exhibit 2, except my outer `UIView` is the `UITableView's` `tableViewHeader` view. Shown below (table view header background maroon, `UIView` in green, `UILabel` grey):

[image: Exhibit 3 Constraints]

I apply the same `layoutSubviews` code to the green `UIView's` subclass.

This time, the `UILabel's` height is not adjusted when the `UILabel's` contents are changed. The `UILabel` and its superview remain the same size, and the text is clipped.

I've also included an example project which contains the three examples described in this post: https://github.com/nsso/flexible-table-header

Does anyone know the reason why my `UILabel's` size is not adjusting the size of the `tableViewHeader` and is there anything I can do differently to ensure my `UITableView's` header view is sized appropriately?